# Changing Databases in Crystal Reports for .NET

Tags: asp.net, crystal-reports

I have a problem which is perfectly described here (http://www.bokebb.com/dev/english/1972/posts/197270504.shtml):

Scenario:

Windows smart client app and the CrystalReportViewer for windows.
Using ServerFileReports to access reports through a centralized and disconnected folder location.

When accessing a report which was designed against DB_DEV and attempting to change its LogonInformation through the CrystalReportViewer to point against DB_UAT, it never seems to actually use the changed information.

It always goes against the DB_DEV info.

Any idea how to change the Database connection and logon information for a ServerFileReport ????

Heres code:

FROM A PRESENTER:

```
// event that fires when the views run report button is pressed
private void RunReport(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
this.view.LoadReport(Report, ConnectionInfo);
}

protected override object Report
{
get
{
ServerFileReport report = new ServerFileReport();
report.ObjectType = EnumServerFileType.REPORT;
report.ReportPath = @"\Report2.rpt";
report.WebServiceUrl = "http://localhost/CrystalReportsWebServices2005/ServerFileReportService.asmx";
return report;

}
}
private ConnectionInfo ConnectionInfo
{
get
{
ConnectionInfo info = new ConnectionInfo();
info.ServerName = servername;
info.DatabaseName = databasename;
info.UserID = userid;
info.Password = password;
return info;
}
}

ON THE VIEW WITH THE CRYSTAL REPORT VIEWER:

public void LoadReport(object report, ConnectionInfo connectionInfo)
{
viewer.ReportSource = report;
SetDBLogon(connectionInfo);
}

private void SetDBLogon(ConnectionInfo connectionInfo)
{
foreach (TableLogOnInfo logOnInfo in viewer.LogOnInfo)
{
logOnInfo.ConnectionInfo = connectionInfo;
}
}
```

Does anyone know how to solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I know this isn't the programatic answer you're looking for, but:

One thing that helps with this sort of thing is not creating your reports connected to the database directly, but first you create a "Data Dictionary" for Crystal Reports (this is done in the Report Designer).  Then you link all of your reports to this dictionary which maps the fields to the proper databases.

Done this way, you only have one place to change the database schema/connection info for all reports.

Also, in your report designer set the report to not cache the results (sorry I don't remember the exact option).  Reports can either have their initial results included or not.

Answer (score 0):

In your CrystalReportViewer object you should set

```
AutoDataBind="true"
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't you have to browse all the "databaseTable" objects of the report to redirect the corresponding connections? You'll find [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/204611/crystal-report-datasource-remap#217756) my VB version of the 'database switch' problem ...